# this.props.match is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app throws TypeError: this.context.params is undefined when trying to get params from the url.

Here is the state of my component :

```
  state = {
    messages : {},
    pseudo : this.props.match.params.pseudo
  }
```

With that kind of url

```
http://localhost:3000/pseudo/aa
```

Here is the route that leads to this page

```
return <Navigate push to={`/pseudo/${this.state.pseudo}`}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by reverting to react-router-dom v. 4.3.1, and by using the Redirect component instead of the Navigate one.